# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: InvalidDocument: cannot encode object: {1}, of type: <class 'set'>

Tags: discord.py, pymongo

So I've been using discord.py to build my own discord bot. However, when using pymongo, I come across this error I cannot figure out. Basically, I want this function to run as an accumulative system that can display the number of warnings (in my case, Yellow cards) a member has picked up when executing the command. But it keeps saying "discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: InvalidDocument: cannot encode object: {1}, of type: <class 'set'>"

I'm not sure what this means but here's the part of the code (yes, the bot can be properly launched but as soon as I use the yellowcard command, the pymongo bit just doesn't seem to work), I've been struggling with it for so long now and it would be wonderful if someone can help:

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def yc(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason = None):
    embed = discord.Embed(Title = "Yellow Card Issued!", description = f'{member.mention} just got Yellow Carded!', color = discord.Colour.blue())
    embed.add_field(name = "Reason:", value = f'**{reason}**', inline = False)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url = member.avatar_url)
    embed.set_footer(icon_url= ctx.author.avatar_url, text= f"Issued by {ctx.author.name}")
    embed.set_image(url= "https://media.giphy.com/media/26n6N6cXfE3Z8JX7G/giphy.gif")
    await ctx.send("**Yellow Card Issued!**")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await ctx.send("<:YellowCard:571349818023346177> **×1**")
    id = member.id
    if collection.count_documents({"memberid":id}) == 0:
        ollection.insert_one({"memberid":id, "yellowcards": 0})
    yellowcardcounts = collection.find_one({"memberid":id})
    count = yellowcardcounts["yellowcards"]
    new_count = count + 1
    num = int(new_count)
    *collection.update_one({"memberid": id}, {"$in": {"Yellowcard_Counts": {num}}})*
    await ctx.send(f'{member.mention}\'s Yellowcard Tally: **{new_count}**! Two Yellowcards result in immediate arrest!')
```

Everything seems to be referring to the line in italic. Here is the full error:

```
Ignoring exception in command yc:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/adrian/Desktop/This is a Folder/Projects/Programming/Python Stuff/Little Green/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/adrian/Desktop/This is a Folder/Projects/Programming/Python Stuff/Little Green/Little Green Script.py", line 90, in yc
    collection.update_one({"memberid": id}, {"$in": {"Yellowcard_Counts": {num}}})
  File "/Users/adrian/Desktop/This is a Folder/Projects/Programming/Python Stuff/Little Green/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 1024, in update_one
    hint=hint, session=session),
  File "/Users/adrian/Desktop/This is a Folder/Projects/Programming/Python Stuff/Little Green/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 870, in _update_retryable
    _update, session)
  File "/Users/adrian/Desktop/This is a Folder/Projects/Programming/Python Stuff/Little Green/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1498, in _retryable_write
    return self._retry_with_session(retryable, func, s, None)
  File "/Users/adrian/Desktop/This is a Folder/Projects/Programming/Python Stuff/Little Green/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1384, in _retry_with_session
    return self._retry_internal(retryable, func, session, bulk)
  File "/Users/adrian/Desktop/This is a Folder/Projects/Programming/Python Stuff/Little Green/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1416, in _retry_internal
    return func(session, sock_info, retryable)
  File "/Users/adrian/Desktop/This is a Folder/Projects/Programming/Python Stuff/Little Green/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 866, in _update
    retryable_write=retryable_write)
  File "/Users/adrian/Desktop/This is a Folder/Projects/Programming/Python Stuff/Little Green/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 836, in _update
    retryable_write=retryable_write).copy()
  File "/Users/adrian/Desktop/This is a Folder/Projects/Programming/Python Stuff/Little Green/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 699, in command
    self._raise_connection_failure(error)
  File "/Users/adrian/Desktop/This is a Folder/Projects/Programming/Python Stuff/Little Green/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 694, in command
    exhaust_allowed=exhaust_allowed)
  File "/Users/adrian/Desktop/This is a Folder/Projects/Programming/Python Stuff/Little Green/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 122, in command
    codec_options, ctx=compression_ctx)
  File "/Users/adrian/Desktop/This is a Folder/Projects/Programming/Python Stuff/Little Green/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/message.py", line 715, in _op_msg
    flags, command, identifier, docs, check_keys, opts)
bson.errors.InvalidDocument: cannot encode object: {1}, of type: <class 'set'>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/adrian/Desktop/This is a Folder/Projects/Programming/Python Stuff/Little Green/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 902, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/Users/adrian/Desktop/This is a Folder/Projects/Programming/Python Stuff/Little Green/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 864, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/Users/adrian/Desktop/This is a Folder/Projects/Programming/Python Stuff/Little Green/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: InvalidDocument: cannot encode object: {1}, of type: <class 'set'>
```

Comment: Why are there `*` surrounding the line of error?

Comment: Also, you're converting `num` into a set of `num`. Maybe use a list or a tuple so that pymongo can parse it?

Comment: "Everything seems to be referring to the line in italic. Here is the full error:"

Sry, should have said surrounded by asterisks

Comment: And apparently tuple doesn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
collection.update_one({"memberid": id}, {"$in": {"Yellowcard_Counts": {num}}})
#                                                                     ^   ^
# Brackets that surround any number of items that are also not dictionaries are sets.
```

In your line of error, you have a set of `num`. Instead of making it a set, just keep it there as an `int` or `str`.

Comment: Looks like it solves the problem. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @Nairda2042 No problem! Remember to accept answers if it solves your problem  ;)